# How to iterate in a loop to generate databases in Postgres for testing?

Tags: postgresql, loops

I want to simulate a distributed database, so I am generating 10 isolated databases, 3 replicas each, for a total of 30 database instances. I am doing this all locally for the moment, and am running something like this:

```
drop database if exists ddsjs_test_1_replica_1;
drop database if exists ddsjs_test_2_replica_1;
drop database if exists ddsjs_test_3_replica_1;
drop database if exists ddsjs_test_4_replica_1;
drop database if exists ddsjs_test_5_replica_1;
drop database if exists ddsjs_test_6_replica_1;
drop database if exists ddsjs_test_7_replica_1;
drop database if exists ddsjs_test_8_replica_1;
drop database if exists ddsjs_test_9_replica_1;
drop database if exists ddsjs_test_10_replica_1;

create database ddsjs_test_1_replica_1;
create database ddsjs_test_2_replica_1;
create database ddsjs_test_3_replica_1;
create database ddsjs_test_4_replica_1;
create database ddsjs_test_5_replica_1;
create database ddsjs_test_6_replica_1;
create database ddsjs_test_7_replica_1;
create database ddsjs_test_8_replica_1;
create database ddsjs_test_9_replica_1;
create database ddsjs_test_10_replica_1;

...
```

How do I make this dynamic in SQL for Postgres? Like looping and incrementing `i`?

Comment: Not sure how you would do this in SQL as you can't create a database within a transaction which you would likely need as part of the incrementing number. You could wrap this in a scripting language script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sample Function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION create_databases_dynamic()
RETURNS bool 
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
declare
    v_index integer;
    sql_drop text;
    sql_create text;
begin
    
    sql_drop   = 'drop database if exists ddsjs_test_%s_replica_1'; 
    sql_create = 'create database ddsjs_test_%s_replica_1';
    
    for v_index in 1..10 
    loop
        EXECUTE format(sql_drop, v_index);
        EXECUTE format(sql_create, v_index);
    end loop;

    return true; 

END;
$function$;
```